# Recursive type-checking with macro in freemarker-template

Tags: java, recursion, freemarker, typechecking

I want to iterate recursive through the keys and values of a LinkedHashMap and print those into a template by using apache freemarker.
The LinkedHashMap contains keys as strings and values as objects. The values can be a LinkedHashMap, ArrayList or String.

The following java sourcecode returns the String, that I want to create by using freemarker.

```
private String printLinkedHashMap(LinkedHashMap<?, ?> map, int counter) {
        if(map == null) {
            return "";
        }
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set<?> set = map.entrySet();
        sb.append(getSpaces(counter) + "<ul>\n");
        for (Object object : set) {
            if(object instanceof Entry<?, ?>) {
                Entry<?, ?> entry = (Entry<?, ?>) object;
                
                sb.append(getSpaces(counter) + "<li>" + entry.getKey() + " = ");
                
                if(entry.getValue() instanceof LinkedHashMap<?, ?>) {
                    sb.append("</li>\n" + printLinkedHashMap((LinkedHashMap<?, ?>) entry.getValue(), counter+1));
                    
                } else if(entry.getValue() instanceof ArrayList<?>){
                    ArrayList<?> listOfValues = (ArrayList<?>) entry.getValue();
                    sb.append("</li>" + printArrayList(listOfValues, counter+1));
                    
                } else {
                    sb.append(entry.getValue().toString() + "</li>\n");
                }
            }
        }
        sb.append(getSpaces(counter) + "</ul>\n");
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    private String printArrayList(ArrayList<?> listOfValues, int counter) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(listOfValues.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.size(); i++) {
                sb.append('\n' + getSpaces(counter));
                sb.append("<li>" + listOfValues.get(i).toString() + "</li>");
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(listOfValues.get(0).toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The output is:

```
<ul>
<li>defaultVar = </li>
    <ul>
    <li>subdefaultVar = </li>
        <ul>
        <li>subsubdefaultVar = defaultValue</li>
        <li>subsubdefaultVariable = defaultValue2</li>
        </ul>
    <li>anothersubdefaultVar = </li>
        <ul>
        <li>anothersubsubdefaultVar = anotherdefaultValue</li>
        <li>anothersubsubdefaultVariable = anotherdefaultValue2</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
<li>defaultVariable = Defaultshort</li>
</ul>
```

The freemarker template contains the following part.

```
<#list map.entrySet() as entry>
  <@printLinkedHashMap entry/>

  <#macro printLinkedHashMap obj>
    <#if obj??>
      <ul>
      <#if obj.key??>  
        <#if obj.key?is_string>
          <li>${obj.key} = 
        </#if>
      </#if>

      <#if obj.value??>

        <#if obj.value?is_hash_ex>
          </li>
          <#list obj.value.entrySet() as entry>
            <@printLinkedHashMap entry/>
          </#list>

        <#elseif obj.value?is_collection>
          </li>
          <ul>
            <#list obj.value as current>
              <li>${current.value}</li>
            </#list>
          </ul>

        <#elseif obj.value?is_string>
          ${obj.value}</li>
        </#if>
      </#if>
      </ul>
    </#if>  
  </#macro>

</#list>
```

When I use this template, the following error will be shown:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> obj.value.entrySet  [in template "template.ftl" at line 55, column 26]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list obj.value.entrySet() as entry  [in template "template.ftl" in macro "printLinkedHashMap" at line 55, column 19]
    - Reached through: @printLinkedHashMap entry  [in template "template.ftl" in macro "printLinkedHashMap" at line 56, column 21]
    - Reached through: @printLinkedHashMap entry  [in template "template.ftl" in macro "printLinkedHashMap" at line 56, column 21]
    - Reached through: @printLinkedHashMap entry  [in template "template.ftl" at line 41, column 11]
----
```

The error shows that 'obj.value.entrySet()' seems to be null. But I don't understand why that happens and how to fix that.

**Solution**
I created a solution for that problem. If someone else needs it, my ftl-file contains the following macro now:

```
<#macro printLinkedHashMap entry>
  <#if entry.key??>
    <ul>
    <#if entry.key??>  
      <#if entry.key?is_string>
        <li>${entry.key} = 
      </#if>
    </#if>

    <#if entry.value??>
      <#if entry.value?is_hash_ex>
        <#if (entry.value.entrySet())??>
          <#list entry.value.entrySet() as newEntry>
            <#if newEntry.key??>
              <#if newEntry.value??>
                <@printLinkedHashMap newEntry/>
              </#if>
            </#if>
          </#list>
        <#elseif entry.value?is_collection>
          <ul>
          <#list entry.value as currentValue>
            <li>currentValue</li>
          </#list>
          </ul>
        <#else>
          ${entry.value}</li>
        </#if>
            
        </li>
      </#if>
    </#if>
    </ul>
  </#if>  
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is that there is an `HashMap` in your structure somewhere instead of a `LinkedHashMap`.

The `HashMap` is wrapped by freemarker into a `SimpleHash`, which doesn't have an `entrySet()` method, which cause the error `obj.value.entrySet has evaluated to null or missing`.

Note that you should prefer to use `map?keys` to iterate over your maps. It will work on both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` (and return the keys in the correct order for the `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` Java members also won't be exposed. It's no different from `HashMap` in this regard.

Comment: @ddekany You're right, but I assumed the OP was using a wrapper with `setExposeFields(true)` (which also explains the use of `obj.key?is_string` in the freemarker template).

Comment: When you see `obj.key` in a template, that usually means `obj.getKey()` or `obj.get("key")` in Java. It's hardly ever field access (although it could be that as well).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the way of accessesing the keys of a map to `map?keys`. In this way, there's also a `StackOverflowException`. Do you have any idea what could go wrong there?

Comment: @Crazy-Tony That's certainly because your object graph contains a loop (a nested map/collection refers back to its own ancestor). So it's infinitely deep if you want to represent it as a tree.

Comment: @ddekany The graph doesn't contain any loops. If I try to access the keys of my map by using `map?keys`, there are also listed functions like `getClass`, `replace`, `containsValue`,... . So the recursive macro tries to iterate through this functions too and that's not the goal, that I want to reach. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Crazy-Tony: If the map contains the methods, then you are using a bad (or at least deprecated) `ObjectWrapper` setup. `DefaultObjectWrapper` doesn't do that (by default). If you have to use pure `BeansWrapper`, you have to set `BeansWrapper.simpleMapWrapper` to `true` to avoid that madness.

Answer (score 0):

Java members of `Map`-s are not exposed by default (especially as they could clash with the keys). Nor `List` members, `String` members, `Date` members, etc. Anything that FreeMarker recognizes as the near equivalent of a basic FTL type won't be exposed as a generic Java object.

If you really need the Java API of a `Map`, you can use `myMap?api.someMethod()`. But, if you just need to list key-value pairs, maybe `<#list myMap as k, v>...</#list>` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I'm using `<#list myMap as k, v>...</#list>` instead of `<#list myMap.entrySet() as entry>...</#list>`.  But the program throws a `StackOverflowException`. Do you have any idea what could go wrong there?